# A-Star Pathfinding choosing bad waypoints

Tags: java, algorithm, path-finding, a-star, heuristics

---

**SOLVED: I'm sorry. I was reconstructing improperly the path. I thought closedSet had all the waypoints from start to end only, but it has some other waypoints too. I miss understood the concept. Now it's working okey!**

---

I'm still getting some trouble with A*.

My character is finding his path, but sometimes, depending where i click on the map, the algorithm finds the shortest path or the path, but with many nodes that shouldn't be selected.

I've tried to follow **Wikipedia's** and **A* Pathfinding for Beginner's** implementation, but they give me the same result. I don't know if it is the heuristic or the algorithm itself, but something's not right.

And this is an example of the problem clicking two different nodes: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXuEm.jpg

Here's the Pathfind class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class Pathfind {
public Pathfind(){

}

public ArrayList<Node> findPath(Node start, Node end, ArrayList<Node> nodes){

    ArrayList<Node> openSet = new ArrayList<Node>();
    ArrayList<Node> closedSet = new ArrayList<Node>();

    Node current;

    openSet.add(start);

    while(openSet.size() > 0){

        current = openSet.get(0);

        current.setH_cost(ManhattanDistance(current, end));

        if(start == end) return null;           
        else if(closedSet.contains(end)){
            System.out.println("Path found!");
            return closedSet;
        }

        openSet.remove(current);
        closedSet.add(current);

        for(Node n : current.getNeigbours()){           
            if(!closedSet.contains(n)){     
                if(!openSet.contains(n) || (n.getG_cost() < (current.getG_cost()+10))){ 
                    n.setParent(current);
                    n.setG_cost(current.getG_cost()+10);
                    n.setH_cost(ManhattanDistance(n, end));

                        if(!openSet.contains(n))
                            openSet.add(n);

                    Collections.sort(openSet);
                }
            }
        }
    }       

    return null;
}

private int ManhattanDistance(Node start, Node end){
    int cost = start.getPenalty();

    int fromX = start.x, fromY = start.y;
    int toX = end.x, toY = end.y;

    return cost * (Math.abs(fromX - toX) + Math.abs(fromY - toY));
}
```

}

Comment: you have 5 if statements nested - i'd recommend using or conditional or putting them all in a method that returns a bool.

Comment: Please add more details about the map. Depending on the type of map, the different distance metric may or may not be correct to be used as the heuristic.

Comment: Just a comment - I believe the choice of `closedSet` as `ArrayList` is not efficient. each `contains()` op is `O(n)` (where `n` is the number of closed nodes). You should use a `Set` for better performance - A `HashSet` is a wise choice, and if you want to maintain the order of insertion - you should use a `LinkedHashSet`. (Note you will have to override `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods of `Node`)

Answer (score 1):

I believe the bug is with the condition:

```
if(n.getCost() < current.getCost()){
```

**You shouldn't prevent advancing if the cost (`g(node)+h(node)`) is decreasing from the current.** Have a look at this counter example: (S is the source and T is the target)

```
_________
|S |x1|x2|
----------
|x3|x4|x5|
---------
|x6|x7|T |
----------
```

Now, Assume you are at S, you haven't moved yet so `g(S) =0`, and under the manhattan distance heuristic, `h(S) = 4`, so you get `f(S)=4`

Now, have a look at `x1,x3`: Assuming you are taking one step to each, they will have `g(x1)=g(x3)=1`, and both will have `h(x1)=h(x3)=3` under the same heuristic. It will result in `f(x1)=f(x3)=4` - and your if condition will cause none to "open", thus once you finish iterating on `S` - you will not push anything to `open` - and your search will terminate.

---

As a side note:

I believe the choice of `closedSet` as `ArrayList` is not efficient. each `contains()` op is `O(n)` (where `n` is the number of closed nodes). You should use a `Set` for better performance - A `HashSet` is a wise choice, and if you want to maintain the order of insertion - you should use a `LinkedHashSet`. (Note you will have to override `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods of `Node`)

Comment: I'm not concerned about speed right now, this is just a test. I first need to get it working. Thanks for the advice, anyway. I've been reading something about it.

Comment: @user1656222: The main issue in the answer still stands. The mentioned condition is wrong, and thus the algorithm fails. The speed issue is just a side note, you can ignore it for now and focus only on the other issue stated in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Do your units walk up/down/left/right only, or can they take diagonals as well?

The one requirement for the A*-heuristic is that it's [admissible](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Admissible_heuristic) - it must never **over**-estimate the actual path-length.  If your units can walk diagonally, then manhatten-distance will over-estimate the path-length, and thus A* is not guaranteed to work.

Comment: But why is no path found? A* is still *complete* without admissible heuristic function, it is just not *optimal*, so I'd suspect it would have found a path - just not the shortest one. Also, euclidean distance is still not admissible if you allow diagonals - assuming diagonal is still counted as one step (for distance of one, h=sqrt(2) while h*=1)

Comment: MY unit doesn't move diagonally. I've uploaded a new image showing the path chosen by the algorithm, the neighboring nodes and the selected node (goal).